# Assert rewriting in JUnit

Tags: java, kotlin, junit

`pytest` has a feature called *[assert rewriting](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/assert.html#assertion-introspection-details)*. You can write code like this:

```py
assert 1 == 1
assert [1, 2, 3] == list(range(1, 3))
assert True
```

Before executing the code above, pytest will rewrite the asserts, adding introspection information into the assertion failure message. This way we get nice assertion failure messages without needing to use functions like `assertEquals`, `assertTrue`, `assertNull`, etc.

Would it be possible to do the same in JUnit? Is it possible to write a compiler plugin that would rewrite this code:

```kotlin
assert(1 == 1)
assert(listOf(1, 2, 3) == (1..3).toList())
assert(True)
```

into this:

```kotlin
assertEquals(1, 1)
assertArrayEquals(listOf(1, 2, 3), (1..3).toList())
assertTrue(True)
```

Comment: Have you checked [spock framework](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.3/data_driven_testing.html)?

Comment: Not sure if it’s relevant but take a look at AssertJ.

Comment: AFAIK `assertEquals` already includes the expected and actual values in the failure message. Isn't the "problem" here that Pytest (ab)uses the language keyword `assert` where JUnit has its assertion libraries which do slightly different things?

Comment: Of course, `assertEquals` includes the correct message. But the point is to get the good error message even without using `assertEquals` and its friends.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `assertEquals`? That's exactly what it's for, whereas the `assert` keyword is for checking conditions in production code, not in unit tests. IMHO Pytest abuses `assert` for its testing, and I wouldn't drag that behavior into other languages. It's also quite the opposite of idiomatic for Java.

Comment: @Robert I think you misunderstand my question.